# How to left-align two columns of text?

Tags: alignment

If I have a text file like this:

```
alpha: 1
beta: 2
gamma: 3
delta: 4
epsilon: 5
```

Is there a way to align the numbers like so?:

```
alpha:   1
beta:    2
gamma:   3
delta:   4
epsilon: 5
```

Comment: See the accepted answer to https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20658/align-a-block-of-code-on-the-basis-of-a-single-character

Comment: @D.BenKnoble this question was asked in 2015, the one you have provide link to was asked in 2019.

Comment: @MaximKim well aware. The question i linked has an accepted answer, however; at any rate, one of them should be closed as a dupe of the other. This seemed a more convenient way to point folks towards answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See accepted answer to [Align a block of code on the basis of a single character](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20658/align-a-block-of-code-on-the-basis-of-a-single-character)

To recap

1. `ggVG` to select all
2. `:'<,'>normal f:5a` you don't have to enter `'<,'>` and also note space at the end. For each line in a selection it will execute normal command to find `:` and add 5 spaces after it
3. goto second space after `epsilon:  <here>` and press `<C-v>` to activate block visual mode
4. `5k` to select one char column up to the first row
5. `<` to dedent everything 1 time
6. `.` repeat it until everything is aligned

PS

[image]

Comment: Instead of `:normal f:5a ` you could also use `:s/:/:     /`

Comment: Indeed `:s/:/:     /` might be used instead. (5 spaces are trimmed by formatting unfortunately)

Answer (score 8):

You can do this with the [vim-lion](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-lion) plugin.

Install it, then place your cursor on the first line. In normal mode, type `glip/`. You'll be prompted to type in a pattern, so just type `\d` to match any digit, and press Enter. It will line up the numbers for you.

Comment: Actually, this can be done with the `gL` operator defined by lion.vim. This operator performs alignment by adding spaces to the right of the alignment character (instead of the left, as with the `gl` operator). The full command would then be `gLip:`.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a method not using any plugin.  The strategy is to use tabs as a temporary column delimiter, then reformat the tabs as spaces.

1. Start by setting [`:set noexpandtab`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27noexpandtab%27) (`noet` for short)
2. Type the text, using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to insert a horizontal tab character after each colon.  It will probably look slightly wrong, like this:

   ```
   alpha:  1
   beta:   2
   gamma:  3
   delta:  4
   epsilon:        5
   ```
3. [`:set tabstop=9`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27tabstop%27)  (`:set ts=9` for short) makes it look as desired:

   ```
   alpha:   1
   beta:    2
   gamma:   3
   delta:   4
   epsilon: 5
   ```

   However, the whitespace is actually a horizontal tab character, not spaces.
4. To indicate that you want spaces instead of tabs, `:set et`.  Then, [`:%retab`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3Aretab) to perform the tabs-to-spaces conversion.

Comment: This is less than ideal, because this just changes how tabs are visualized in vim, if someone else were to open the file in a different editor it wouldn't look as good.

Comment: @DhruvaSagar How so? The result is exactly identical after the tabs-to-spaces conversion in step 4.

Comment: Different editors visualize / deal with tabs differently.

Comment: hmm ok, I guess I overlooked step #4. Sorry for that, my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another method that doesn't use any plugins.

First replace the spaces with much bigger spaces. No need to be precise: just mash the <kbd>Space</kbd> key a bunch of times:

```
:%s/ /        /
```

Now trim them all to be the same length:

```
:%norm! 10|dw
```

The only tricky part is knowing what count to use. For this example it's fairly easy, The longest line contains a 7 letter word: `epsilon` plus 2 more characters (a colon and a space), so you need to use a count of 9 + 1.

For more complicated alignments you might benefit by having your current cursor position displayed in your statusline (or by using something like `getcurpos()`).

Alternatively, you can just position the cursor manually on each line and use normal-mode <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> [by hand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28414916/328936).

You can also use this technique [in a macro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8363443/328936):

```
qqf:a    <Esc>10|dw+q4@q
     └──┤
        └─ Mash space bar here
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this plugin: [vim-easy-align](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align).

Answer (score 1):

if you're on a unix environment you could just run

```
%!column -t
```

But if you're on windows, and you have git installed, that means you could use one of the fancy unix tools installed :) Tools like grep, tee, which, and *column* can be found here:

```
%localappdata%\Programs\Git\usr\bin
```

Running the column command from inside Vim then looks like this:

```
:%!C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\usr\bin\column.exe -t
```

Answer (score 0):

My attemp to solve the issue

```
vip ............... select paragraph
:'<,'>!column -t    align
:%norm $X ......... remove one space
```