# Get comments LINED UP in 65c816 asm syntax

Tags: vimscript, indentation, formatting

I've been writing some 65c816 assembly lately. They have some interesting commenting conventions that I was hoping VIM could help me with.

```
        LDA $E7         ; You see, they
        BEQ IfZero      ; put comments like this,
        INC A           ; all lined up with 1 TAB
        STA $E7         ; after the longest line.
IfZero:
        BRK ; and this is a comment that is not lined up correctly
        CPY      ; this one too!
```

I was wondering if there is a clever way to have all the **comments** in the file (or in a selection) lined up **on the same column**.

Desired result:

```
        LDA $E7         ; You see, they
        BEQ IfZero      ; put comments like this,
        INC A           ; all lined up with 1 TAB
        STA $E7         ; after the longest line.
IfZero:
        BRK             ; and this is a comment that is not lined up correctly (now it is)
        CPY             ; this one too!
```

Comment: If you search this site for "align", you can find lots of answers you can apply to this problem. This is my favourite question on the subject: [How to left-align two columns of text?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/594/how-to-left-align-two-columns-of-text)

Comment: Hmmm. Although possibly I misread the question. Are you saying you want to _keep_ one tab character between the commands and the comments, but just display all the comments lined up? If so, you just need to do `:setlocal tabstop=24`